# python Xarray lenght mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-xarray

I'm learning the Xarray library and I'm trying to create Xarrays for 3D data. The following snippet does not work:

```
>>> colx = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
>>> coly = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> colz = ['b1', 'b2']
>>> t = xr.DataArray(np.zeros((4,3,2)),dims = {'x', 'y','z'}, coords={'x':colx, 'y': coly, 'z': colz})
>>> t
ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'x': length 3 on the data but length 4 on coordinate 'x'
```

The following code works, but I need to permute round the lenghts of the x,y,z dimensions to  create the Xarray. The dimensions (4,3,2) get permuted to (3,2,4).

```
>>> colx = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
>>> coly = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> colz = ['b1', 'b2']
>>> t = xr.DataArray(np.zeros((4,3,2)),dims = {'x', 'y','z'}, coords={'x':coly, 'y': colz, 'z': colx})
>>> t
<xarray.DataArray (z: 4, x: 3, y: 2)>
array([[[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]]])
Coordinates:
 * x        (x) <U2 'a1' 'a2' 'a3'
 * y        (y) <U2 'b1' 'b2'
 * z        (z) <U2 'c1' 'c2' 'c3' 'c4'
```

- Is this normal?
- Why is this happening?
- How do the permutations work for higher-dimensional data?

Comment: Try specifying `dims` as a `list`, e.g. `dims=['x', 'y', 'z']`, instead of a `set`.  The elements of a `set` are not guaranteed to be ordered in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying dims as a list, e.g. dims=['x', 'y', 'z'], instead of a set does the trick, see comment by spencerclark.