# Iterating over Xarray resample skips elements

Tags: python, loops, python-xarray, resample

I have a really long dataset in Xarray that I must resample using both a custom function and the mean function to create a new dataset with both data.
To do this, I do

```
ds_res = ds.resample(time=freq)

ds_mean = ds_res.mean('time')

aux_time = []    ;   aux_custom = []
for time,data in ds_res:
    aux_time.append(time)
    aux_custom.append( custom_function(data) )

new_ds = xarray.Dataset( ... )  #Merge both ds_mean and aux_custom over the coord time
```

This works well ALMOST every time, but sometimes the length of the aux lists are smaller than the length of the resample:

```
len(ds_res) > len(aux_time)
```

So when I try to create the new dataframe it gives me the error of `"ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimensions ..."`

Any idea why this happens?? I checked the for loop and it really does less iterations than the length of the resampled dataset.
Maybe it is because of NaN values or something, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Dataset` parameter `data_vars`, each dimension must have the same length in all variables in which it appears, as described [here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html).

Are you specifying `dims` as a `set` instead of a `list`?

Maybe the example from this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60529275/16116707

Comment: I am specifying them as a list. The problem is precisely that the for loop doesn't iterate over the whole resample, giving an smaller array (so the lenght doesn't match and it fails). The resampled ds has a lenght of over 77k and the loop has 12 elements less for reasons unknown to me